# Rspec - Using variable defined in a let statement in another let statement

Tags: ruby, rspec2

In my RSpec test, I have defined multiple methods using let() syntax. I have encountered a scenario where I need to use variable defined inside a let statement into another let statement inside same describe block.

```
 context 'Reuse the name of first car in the second car' do
    it_behaves_like 'some car test' do

      let(:car1) do {
          name1: "#{testcase['Car']}_#{Time.now.round}",
          car_model: testcase['Toyota']
      }

      end

      let(:car2) do {
          name2: name1
      }
      end
    end
  end
```

As you can see I want to use the exact name value I defined `name1` inside `:car1` for `name2` inside `:car2`. The above syntax throws me following error

```
NameError:
       undefined local variable or method `name1' for #<RSpec::
```

How do I use exact value of `name1` in `:car2`? Any ideas..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
let(:name1) { "#{testcase['Car']}_#{Time.now.round}" }

let(:car1) { { name1: name1, car_model: testcase['Toyota'] } }

let(:car2) { { name2: name1 } }
```

So `name1` is also now a lazy variable to initialized when is called, if not for car1, then for car2.

If the Time.now is a problem, you can leave the value of name1 as `testcase['Car']` and then just interpolate the value of Time.now.

Comment: Thank You @Sebastian Palma. I got the idea now.

Answer (score 2):

`name1` is a key in the hash defined as `car1`, therefore you need to use the hash syntax to get its value:

```
let(:car1) do 
  {
    name1: "#{testcase['Car']}_#{Time.now.round}",
    car_model: testcase['Toyota']
  }
end

let(:car2) do 
  {
    name2: car[:name1]
  }
end
```

Please note that this only answers your question on how to extract the value, I do not suggest writing specs like that. If both cars should share the same name than Sebastian's answer is probably clearer and easier to understand.

Answer (score 0):

let definitions work just fine with each other.

You defined two things: `car1` and `car2`. 
Code is throwing an error about `name1`. You just didnt define it.

I guess you need to read more about ruby [Hash](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/Hash.html) and [Symbol](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.0/Symbol.html).